# Entity Framework - Contains Method

Tags: entity-framework, contains

Someone has an answer to this missing feature in Entity Framework.  Does anyone have a solution to the missing Contains method in Entity Framework that *works*?  I've tried a number of those on here and through Google, but none of them seem to actually work.

Comment: The one which is already posted on this site works for me. You're going to need to be more specific about what you are presently doing, and what part about it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using EF 4.0 it's implemented there also StartsWith, EndsWith and many others.
[ADO.NET Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/10/22/new-features-in-entity-framework-impacting-providers.aspx)

Comment: Ooo, do you know where it can be downloaded?  And if it works with VS 2008?

Comment: EF 4 comes with VS2010, requires .NET 4, and doesn't work with VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already answered, Entity Framework 4.0 Beta 2 has support for this method, but it requires Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 to be downloaded. 
In Visual Studio 2008 SP1 you can either use manual LINQ expressions construction, like it is described [here](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=42399), or Entity SQL, like we have already recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978747/how-to-get-objectresult-from-entity-framework-using-a-list-of-identities/995132#995132).