# How to create ObjectResult<T> from HashSet<T>?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get ObjectResult from Entity Framework using a list of Identities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978747/how-to-get-objectresult-from-entity-framework-using-a-list-of-identities)

NET gurus,

Does anybody know how to create `ObjectResult<int>` from `HashSet<Int>` ?
I am writing a unit test for MVC controller and have to override a function:

```
public ObjectResult<TElement> ExecuteStoreQuery<TElement>(string commandText, 
                                                          params Object[] parameters)
```

I can create `HashSet<TElement>` but don’t know how to make it into `ObjectResult<TElement>`.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.