# Thoughts on highest performance method regarding LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a table which totals **350448** records of which I need to perform multiple, repetitive queries through LINQ with Entity Framework.

The amount of these repetitive queries is approximately **1440**, I cannot modify the database.

What would be the best way in terms of performance:

- Select all 350448 records and query them on the client
- Perform the 1440 queries against the database
- Attempt to narrow down the data first, then perform the query on the client

I need to be able to do a lookup for 1440 items basically, but I'm aware of the possible performance problems.

Comment: One lookup for 1440 items isn't the same as 1440 queries. Please provide more information.

Comment: I have a list of 1440 `DateTime` which need to be looked up and a value returned.  I can't see any other way then perform a query for each?

Comment: @m.edmonson: Are these batches matching exact values?

Comment: @JonSkeet - No, each lookup will return a unique value - it's basically converting a UTC date to an industry specific date.  There are logical rules so I can't just write a function to do the conversion.

Comment: Best way would be to upload the 1440 values to sql server either by using a table variable (2008 only i think) or a temp table and then running one query against the table containing your 1440 values - I have no idea how you would actually implement using EF though

Comment: @m.edmondson: But it's an exact match, is what I mean? Not some sort of inequality test etc?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Sorry yes, there is no ambiguity, each will return exactly one specific date which can be looked up exactly

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you *may* be able to get away with:

```
List<DateTime> dates = ...;
var query = context.MyEntities
                   .Where(x => dates.Contains(x.LastUpdated))
                   .ToList();
```

However:

- I'm not *sure* whether EF supports `Contains` in the same way that LINQ to SQL does
- You may need to break the query into a few batches; it depends whether EF is smart enough to use a table-valued parameter (and whether your database supports it).

Comment: One query batch which returns 1440 records will be a lot faster than 1440 query batches.

Comment: @m.edmondson: I'd expect it to be good, yes. Why don't you try it and see whether a) it works and b) it's *good enough*

Comment: @m.edmondson: It works with Entity Framework but unfortunately `Contains` is known to be *horrible* slow, especially if the `dates` list has "many" entries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8108643/270591

Comment: It will be slow, yes, but much faster than doing 1440 individual queries. It will be as fast as it can be expected.