# Select multiple columns in LINQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I've written a LINQ query shown below :

```
List<Actions> actions = resourceActions.Actions.Select(s => s.ActionName).ToList();
```

How do I give for selecting multiple columns here ? ie I want to add columns `s.ActionId` and `s.IsActive`. I'm unable to apply it.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11592103/985284

Comment: cant you use a container or something. so resourceActions.Actions.Select(s => new Container(s.ActionName,...)).ToList();.. you will  obviously need to find a suitable container

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make a class to represent the data you want:

```
public class ResourceAction
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

Select a list of those instead:

```
List<ResourceAction> actions = resourceActions.Actions
  .Select(s => new ResourceAction() { Id = s.Id, Name = s.ActionName}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what your looking for. However you need to change the output to an anonymous  type.

```
var actions = resourceActions.Actions.Select(s => new { s.ActionName, s.ActionId, s.IsActive } ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a anonymous type for this, for example

```
var actions = resourceActions.Actions.Select(s => 
    new { Id = s.Id, Name = s.ActionName, Active = s.IsActive).ToList();
```

but a better way would be to create a class like

```
public class ActionWithId
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
}

List<ActionWithId> actions = resourceActions.Actions.Select(s => 
    new ActionWithId() { Id = s.Id, Name = s.ActionName, Active = s.IsActive }).ToList();
```