# Entity Framework IN clause on navigation property

Tags: entity-framework

I have a object IQueryable which I am trying to dynamically add Where clauses, this works great for columns on Listing object, however now conditionally I would like to add a IN clause to a navigation property (ListingAmenities) which has columns ListingID, AmenityID

I have critiera.AmenityIDs which may contain Amenities I like to filter the results on.

I am trying to achieve the following if there is any amenityIDs in my array

```
select * from Listings l inner join ListingAmenities a on l.ListingID = a.ListingID where a.AmenityID IN(1,2,3)
```

here is my code (I am using EF5)

```
if (criteria.AmenityIDs.Count > 0)
        {
            listings = listings.Where(x => x.ListingAmenities.Any(y => y.AmenityID == criteria.AmenityIDs));
        }
```

which of course does not work.
Important note is that I am adding these WHERE clauses dynamically so that is why I am building up a IQueryable object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enumerable.Contains` translates into `IN` in SQL, so you can use:

```
if (criteria.AmenityIDs.Count > 0)
{
    listings = listings.Where(x => x.ListingAmenities
        .Any(y => criteria.AmenityIDs.Contains(y.AmenityID)));
}
```

Be careful if the `AmenityIDs` collection is very long because `Contains` has [performance problems for large collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108643/270591). But 100 elements or so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I would have no more than 12 items in the array