# Can Entity Framework work with multiple result sets for includes?

Tags: entity-framework

When I query for the entity and add many includes to my query data is denormalized.
Many rows contain data which differs only by a few columns whereas other columns contain the same data.
Before I started using ORM I preferred to write several queries and receive multiple result sets assembling complex objects by hand. Though the optimal approach depends on the schema, number of returned records and complexity of the entities.

I want to know whether EF supports the second way of instantiating complex entities and how I can switch this mode on.

**Update**

To be more clear I'll exaggerate a little.

Suppose we have entity `A` consisting of 100 hundred simple properties: strings, interges, dates and so on. Besides these properties entity contains a very large collection of entities `B`.

Let's consider the query:

```
context.ASet.Include("CollectionOfB");
```

For each item B contained in the collection server returns many duplicates of A's simple properties.

Without ORM I create the query but ask only for the ids of the root objects. Then I query for the root objects, after that I query for the dependencies which reference root object ids.
Then I process MARS with dictionaries and hash sets to assemble entities.

Comment: Are you using stored procedures?

Comment: No, just queries. SPs are static, I know EF 5 supports MRS in SPs, but I'm looking for the way to optimize queries concerning the size of returned data.

Comment: Have you looked into compiled queries? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx

Comment: Yes, sure. But CQs helps to decrease the time of query construction and we need to decrease amount of data returned from the server.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.  Can't you write the query to return only the results you want?  Otherwise, stored procedure import....?

Comment: It looks to me like you are micro-optimizing which is probably not going to be valuable for you. You *can* do this but I think it will actually end up being slower as it needs to span 2 queries.

Comment: Perhaps what would be a more useful question is 'how can i exclude properties I'm not interested in from my result set?'

Comment: @Luke I disagree. It is not a micro-optimizing. And I need all properties, but I don't want them to be repeated many times in the returned result.

Answer (score 2):

If the set of `Root` entities is not too large you could try explicit loading (syntax for `DbContext`):

```
var roots = context.Roots.Where(someCondition).ToList();
foreach (var root in roots)
    root.Children = context.Entry(root).Collection(r => r.Children)
        .Query().ToList();
```

This works for any kind of relationship including many-to-many relationships. There are 1 + N queries and it will be probably counterproductive with respect to performance compared to eager loading if N is too large.

If the relationship between `Root` and `Child` is *not* many-to-many you can leverage *Relationship Fixup* which is a feature of the context (`ObjectContext` or `DbContext`) that ensures that the object graph is built up automatically when the entities get loaded into or attached to the context:

```
var roots = context.Roots.Where(someCondition).ToList();
var rootIds = roots.Select(r => r.Id);
context.Children.Where(c => rootIds.Contains(c.Root.Id)).Load();
```

(I am assuming here that `Child` has an inverse navigation property `Root`.)

These are always *two* queries, no matter how many `Root` entities are loaded. Relationship Fixup will populate the `root.Children` collection automatically for every attached `root` so that the result looks *as if* you had used eager loading:

```
var roots = context.Roots.Include("Children").Where(someCondition).ToList();
```

Unfortunately the `Contains` method is slow if the `rootIds` collection is large: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108643/270591. But it still might be better up to a certain number of `rootIds` than the performance  hit caused by the data duplication when you use eager loading.

Prefering one of the alternatives is a matter of test. I could not give a general advice to use one or the other option that would be right for all situations.

Comment: Earlier I worked with generated entity classes with fixups in properties. Is it the same as Relation Fixup or something different. And will this work for disabled changes tracking?

Comment: @voroninp: No, it's not the same. The "Relationship Fixup" that I mean has nothing to do with that property fixup code in generated entities. It's a context core feature available for all types of entities and in all EF versions. And no, it won't work with disabled change tracking. Sorry, I forgot to emphasize it in the first place.