# Entity Framework 6: Slow "WHERE NOT IN" statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0 with SQL Server localdb, I tried using the Enumerable.Contains feature, but I found it very slow when we have a big list.

I researched and found that there is a recommendation to use sql statements for this case, as described in:[Why is .Contains slow? Most efficient way to get multiple entities by primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107439/entity-framework-4-1-most-efficient-way-to-get-multiple-entities-by-primary-key/28110523#28110523).

Now I wonder why the following statement is so slow, taking more than 180 seconds to run the "ToList ()"?

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    var ids = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        ids.Add(rand.Next(550000));

    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    var values = new StringBuilder();
    values.AppendFormat("{0}", ids[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < ids.Count; i++)
        values.AppendFormat(", {0}", ids[i]);

    var sql = string.Format(
        "SELECT * FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[MyEntities] WHERE NOT [ID] IN ({0})",
        values);

    var result = context.Set<MyEntity>().SqlQuery(sql).ToList();

    watch.Stop();
    var msec = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

Note that the statement is similar to the link test3 above, except that we included the term "NOT".

Sorry my bad English^^.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to potential sql injection attacks!

Comment: How long does it take to execute this sql directly?

Comment: You are using newer version of Entityframework which has better support for [Enumerable.Contains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/10/17/ef6-rtm-available.aspx).

Comment: The total execution time of this statement is 226 seconds.
I'm using the latest version available on nuget: 6.1.2. It is also very slow if I run the statement in the latest LinqPad 4:51:03

Comment: @DanielA.White Generally that would be true, but in this case the values are all guaranteed to be integers (at least in the example).

Comment: Yes, the ID is integer.

Comment: How long does it take for EF to execute the query?  In other words, can you move the watch.Start() to after building the query?

Comment: Same time, the others lines are irrelevant. Only the line "var result = DbLocal.Set<Cliente>().SqlQuery(sql).ToList();" that is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a very large filter condition to the database like you are doing can be very slow. Depending on the size of the table it can be much faster to retrieve all the values and do the filtering in memory instead using a `HashSet`. Try this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
var set= new HashSet<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
    set.Add(rand.Next(550000));

Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

var sql = "SELECT * FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[MyEntities]";

var result = context.Set<MyEntity>()
             .SqlQuery(sql)
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Where(x => !set.Contains(x.ID))
             .ToList();

watch.Stop();
```

Comment: If i execute the statement directly in sql server, in the first time ir execute in 11 seconds, but i will test your suggestion.

Comment: Also if you table contains many columns only retrive the ones you actually need, it can save a lot of time using this solution.

Comment: The table has 19 columns.
Please know tell me why this absurd difference runtime?
If I run directly in sql server: 11 seconds.
The entity framework using sql statement: 226 seconds.

Comment: @Zeus-Adenilton Let me know which timings you got with this solution.

Comment: Your example runs in 5 seconds, due to the number of records in this table is only 10399. Do you have any suggestions for when the number of rows is much higher?

Comment: @Zeus-Adenilton It largely depends on the the size of each row. If small this solution should work fine on very large tables. So only retrieve the columns you actually need.

Comment: I will use this alternative, but it is not what I expect from the Entity Framework. This is basic select any DBMS runs in seconds, for this scenario. Will bug?

Answer (score 0):

When using EF to run your queries the execution time combines of several things:

- time to build and translate the query
- time to run the query and receive results
- time to materialize query results into entities

By using SQL directly with `SqlQuery` method you are omitting the time to build the query and translate it into SQL.

In your case this time will be relatively small compared to query execution and result materialization (which can take quite a lot of time if there are too many results to materialize).

You should check how much time does it take to run the query directly and how many results does it return (if there are too many, like thousands of results, then you should try to minimize the query result or use paging to get the data in relatively small chunks).

Comment: My entity contains 10399 rows. This query returns 330 rows em 226 segundos.