# IQueryable being 3 times as slow with Contain-method vs Array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have some records which I fetch from database (normally about 100-200). I also need to get the corresponding `Place` for every record and fill in the `Description` of the `Place` in the record. I would normally do that in my `.Select` function but I need to check if `Place` isn't null before trying to take the `Description`. My code goes like this:

```
var places = db.Places.Where(p => p.Active && p.CustomerID == cust_ID).ToArray();

foreach (var result in query)
    result.Description = 
     places.Where(Place.Q.Contains(result.Latitude, result.Longitude).Compile())
           .FirstOrDefault()?.Description;
```

`query` is `IQueryable`.

If I take places as `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` and remove the `Compile()` from my Expression, my code runs 3x (!!!) as slow as when I run the code as shown here. 
Does anyone have an explanation for that? Does `places` get fetched from database every loop of foreach?

*(Edit as my first question was answered)*

**Also is there any way I could check if `Place` is null in my `Select` function (not taking the results into memory, keeping it `IQueryable`) so I don't have to loop over my results afterwards?**

Comment: Two questions here. The main one is a dupe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107439/entity-framework-4-1-most-efficient-way-to-get-multiple-entities-by-primary-key . You might choose to rephrase things, because I'll be coming back to this with my dupehammer. The top answer in the link above is a superb answer. Well worth a thorough read.

Comment: There's no way by reading the title of that question that I'd think it answers the question about `Contain`...

Comment: I only know about it because it was asked by a colleague of mine...

Comment: "Does places get fetched from database every loop of foreach?" - Of course not - ToArray() fetch data only once, and after that u're querying to data in memory

Comment: I know it gets fetched only once when I call `ToArray()`, but my point is that my program runs 3x slower If I don't call it and leave places as Queryable, so what's the reason for that?

Comment: @spender Very interesting read indeed, also a very clear approach of testing different methods, cheers for that!. Looks like the Linq-to-sql `.Contain()` method is a no-go. Does anyone know if there's any way I could check if `Place` is null in my select before taking the description? Maybe the best way is to  define a model and pass the `Place` to a property.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck There's something fishy about your `.Where` statement above. Shouldn't there be a lambda in it?

Comment: My `Place` class contains a `Q` class with expressions in it with lambdas I often use. (the .Contains of `Q` is an extension method, should've clarified that)