# EntityFramework performance for matching with a conversion table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a list of `Foo` coming into a process (not entities) and I need to make a 1-1 equivalence on a specific property using Entity Framework Core, having a `Conversion` table. The `Conversion` table is quite stable, and both properties are indexed.

I am wondering if there is a recommended way of doing it, as a rule of thumb, to get the best performances. I have around 10k Equivalence in the table.

Here are the three ways I am thinking of:

- **Query the `Conversion` table for every record**, the key property being indexed. But it makes a lot of queries to the database, which is usually not recommended.
- **Load the whole `Conversion` table in memory** anytime I process a batch of `Foo`. But it loads a lot of data, most of them being useless.
- **Load only the `Conversion` table part I need for a specific batch**, but it requires to send a List of properties to check against the table to the database, which I've usually found to be highly inefficient as well. There is extensive discussions about using the *Contains* operator with EntityFramework, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108643/9446598) but most of them are quite old.

Is there any way to guess depending on (datatypes / number of records / frequency of batches / db performance / etc. ) or do I have to test extensively?

```
public class Foo
{
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string PreferedAnimal { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Not populated at the entry point of the process
    /// </summary>
    [NotMapped]
    public string AssignedPetShop { get; set; }
}

public class Conversion
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string PreferedAnimal { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string AssignedPetShop { get; set; }

}

public class FooPetShopMatcher
{
    private DbContext1 _context;

    public FooPetShopMatcher(DbContext1 context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    public void MatchFoos1(ref List<Foo> foos)
    {
       
        foreach (Foo foo in foos)
        {
            //Sends N query to the database
            foo.AssignedPetShop = _context.Conversion.Single(x => x.PreferedAnimal == foo.PreferedAnimal).AssignedPetShop; 
        }
        return;
    }

    public void MatchFoos2(ref List<Foo> foos)
    {
        //Sends 1 query to the database but loads a lot of useless data
        var dic = _context.Conversion.ToDictionary(x => x.PreferedAnimal, x => x.AssignedPetShop);  

        foreach (Foo foo in foos)
        {
            foo.AssignedPetShop = dic[foo.PreferedAnimal];
        }
        return;
    }

     public void MatchFoos3(ref List<Foo> foos)
    {

        var preferedAnimals = foos.Select(x => x.PreferedAnimal).Distinct().ToArray();

        //Sends 1 query to the database but send a big list, which seems to be highly inefficient
        var dic = _context.Conversion
            .Where(x=> preferedAnimals.Contains(x.PreferedAnimal))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.PreferedAnimal, x => x.AssignedPetShop);  


        foreach (Foo foo in foos) {
            foo.AssignedPetShop = dic[foo.PreferedAnimal];
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Following @Maxim Zabolotskikh comment, here are some insights :

- There are 10k `Conversion`items, and once the table is filled, it never changes under normal operations
- `Foos` are coming by bath of 50-100, once every minute
- We can assume that `Foos` are random

Comment: I'd say you will have to test for yourself. How many Foos come at a time? How often? Are these normally the same Foos as in the other requests (fill memory Cache as requests come and purge it after some time) or completely different? How is the Convertion table filled and how is it updated? There are just too many variables to answer the question. If these are just user REST requests where you get a Petshop based on animal once per request, I'd say you are still ok if you query every time. Only if your really see it gets slow, think about caching.

Comment: Ok, yes I didn't expect a perfect answer but some hints to take a decision. Thanks anyway. To clarify : there are 10k conversion entitities, Foos will come by 50-100, once every minute, and we can assume there are perfectly random.